# Finding where the surface $z=2 + x + y^2$ intersects the $xy$ plane

Tags: calculus

I completely understand all you have to do is set $z = 0$ in order to find where the surface $z=2 + x + y^2$ intersects the $xy$ plane - I just do not understand how to solve this equation, wouldn't there be multiple solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z=0$ then you get $x+y^2=-2$ and that is a whole set of solutions. It describes a parabola in the $xy$ plane. If you cut the three dimensional solid with a knife as the $xy$ plane, your cross section will be that parabola.